# Forms Authentication RedirectUrl does not appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

**Problem:**

Using MVC and ASP.NET Forms Authentication, and while accessing Unauthorized pages, the Login page does open up, but the `RedirectUrl` isn't formed, which by default is the job of `Forms Authentication`.

What could be the reason? and how can I fix this?

Comment: The reason is surely something unusual you have in your setup as it should just work. You'd have to provide more details.

Comment: @WiktorZychla what kind of info?

Comment: whatever. Does it happen on a fresh project with bare minimum setup?